# DjVu Viewer Firefox plugin crash

Tags: firefox-extensions, djvu

After making a clean install of 12.04 and installing DjVuLibre Firefox plugin it crashes everytime I open access a djvu file. Firefox simply says that the plugin has crashed and I should try reloading the page - obviously it doesn't work. There's no error message per se but give me a sign and should it be necessary I'll add more info.

Note - everything worked fine on 11.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade djvu from 4.9-1 to 4.9-2 from the Debian Sid repository. It worked for me.

Instructions found [here](http://thanhsiang.org/faqing/node/175).